# Error with URL after Shopware Docker install

Tags: php, docker, url, apache2, shopware

I am trying to use Shopware 6 (6.2.0_1589874223) in a Docker (Ubuntu 20.04) container. The installation was successful. Now though all the urls are wrong. They have localhost added to their link, i.e. http://localhost:8080/http://localhost:8080/index.php/account/login

There is one localhost too much. My guess is that it first adds a http://localhost:8080 inside the container and then again outside. Assuming this is right, I would believe that the server name has to be set somewhere.

From the technical perspective I just installed Apache2, MySQL and PHP inside the container and then copy and run the contents of `install_6.2.0_1589874223.zip` (Community Edition downloaded from the [Shopware site](https://www.shopware.com/en/download/#shopware-6)) in `/var/www/html`. I then expose the port 80 from the container and then run the container using this command:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name shopware-test -i myshopware/shopware-test:0.0.1
```

Comment: Is the url in sales_channel_domains correct?

Comment: Where do I check that exactly?

Comment: Database sales_channel_domains